# Looking for help Setting up Particles in 1.14 Minecraft

Tags: java, math, minecraft, particles, minecraft-forge

I've been working on this for a while now,

I'm trying to make my own particle but i'm having issues figuring out How everything registers and how i can get my particle to be called modid:particle so essentially registering it to my mod.

Also If someone can help me with my math, I'm looking to have my particle slowly move up from inside the block to about .5blocks above the original block.

I've tried a lot, to list it all would be insane. I did however manage to get a lava particle to appear, I tried different math, different options for spawning the particle, old methods which i modified to work in 1.14 but no matter what it says "name minecraft:enchantblack entered too late"

https://github.com/drizzs/GrassWorld-1.14/tree/master/src/main/java/com/drizzs/grassworld/api/particle <--- My Mod

https://github.com/minecraftabnormals/Upgrade-Aquatic/tree/master/src/main/java/com/teamabnormals/upgrade_aquatic/client/particle <--- working particle

Doing what he did is not an option! I have to find my own methods to do the same thing. As my particles are not the same.

I expect a particle to appear in different sizes making the block to appear as though its magical.

Game instantly crashes when i try my block

https://pastebin.com/TTA7p9iu

I will add any info if you ask for it! If you would prefer to explain how I can do the math or refer me to math resources i'll gladly accept those! Anything I can do to progress I dont specifically need you to do it for me. I just want some help guiding myself!

```
protected EnchantedBlack(World world, double x, double y, double z) {
    super(world, x, y, z, 0.0D, 0.0D, 0.0D);
    this.motionX *= 0;
    this.motionY *= 0.800000011920929D;
    this.motionZ *= 0;
    this.motionY = (double) (this.rand.nextFloat() * 0.4F + 0.05F);
    this.particleScale *= this.rand.nextFloat() * 2.0F + 0.2F;
    this.maxAge = (int) (16.0D / (Math.random() * 0.8D + 0.2D));
}

    public void tick() {
    this.prevPosX = this.posX;
    this.prevPosY = this.posY;
    this.prevPosZ = this.posZ;
    float f = (float)this.age / (float)this.maxAge;

    if (this.age++ >= this.maxAge) {
        this.setExpired();
    } else {
        this.motionY -= 0.03D;
        this.move(this.motionX, this.motionY, this.motionZ);
        this.motionX *= 0.1D;
        this.motionY *= 0.9990000128746033D;
        this.motionZ *= 0.1D;
        if (this.onGround) {
            this.motionX *= 0.699999988079071D;
            this.motionZ *= 0.699999988079071D;
        }
    }

}
public IParticleRenderType getRenderType() {
    return IParticleRenderType.PARTICLE_SHEET_OPAQUE;
}

public float getScale(float float1) {
    float f = ((float)this.age + float1) / (float)this.maxAge;
    return this.particleScale * (1.0F - f * f);
}

@OnlyIn(Dist.CLIENT)
public static class Factory implements IParticleFactory<BasicParticleType> {
    private final IAnimatedSprite spriteSet;

    public Factory(IAnimatedSprite p_i50495_1_) {
        this.spriteSet = p_i50495_1_;
    }

    public Particle makeParticle(BasicParticleType typeIn, World worldIn, double x, double y, double z, double xSpeed, double ySpeed, double zSpeed) {
        EnchantedBlack enchantedblack = new EnchantedBlack(worldIn, x, y, z);
        enchantedblack.selectSpriteRandomly(this.spriteSet);
        return enchantedblack;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First, if you haven't, you should update to 1.14.4 at this point.

Anyway. I am not able to tell what, exactly, is going wrong with what you have, but hopefully my experiences having done this the other day will help.

The crash you have is on [line 84](https://github.com/drizzs/GrassWorld-1.14/blob/master/src/main/java/com/drizzs/grassworld/blocks/normalgrass/OrangeGrass.java#L84) and is an `ExceptionInInitializerError: null`, what this means is that something--during the stage where a class is loaded into the JVM but before its created an instance of anything--encountered a problem. The only thing at this line that could do that would be the reference to `GWParticleTypes.ENCHANTEDBLACK`.

My guess would be that it is [this line](https://github.com/drizzs/GrassWorld-1.14/blob/master/src/main/java/com/drizzs/grassworld/api/particle/GWParticleTypes.java#L32) that is throwing a null. I don't have anything like this, nor am I using that method of adding particles myself. Either the registry is coming back null or something is happening further in that we don't have an eye on. As ParticleTypes aren't an `IForgeRegistryEntry` type and the registry is controlled purely by Vanilla, I suspect that using this method won't work.

As you're using a client side only particle (the `animateTick` method being marked with `@OnlyIn(Dist.CLIENT)`) you should be able to use `Minecraft.getInstance().particles.addEffect(particle);` instead, as I do [here](https://github.com/Draco18s/ReasonableRealism/blob/1.14.4/src/main/java/com/draco18s/harderores/proxy/ClientProxy.java#L40).

My particles are generated server side, sending a packet to the correct player client, and constructing the actual Particle instances on the client, so there's some redirection involved. You will still need to route things through your sided proxy, as you can't reference client side only classes in common code (`@OnlyIn(Dist.CLIENT)` does not prevent you from having to write code the server can validate!), but `addEffect` should simplify things drastically.

As to getting the correct visual effect (the particles rise up off the block) your main problem is likely in this line:

```
this.motionY -= 0.03D;
```

You're making them move *down,* not up. Similarly this line:

```
this.motionY *= 0.9990000128746033D;
```

Will make them move more slowly each frame (in the absense of other factors) due to "air resistance" as the particle code you've copied (either the block-break or the floating-sand particle) is representing a fine dust-like object that falls down from above and lands on the ground. You also won't need `this.onGround` or anything that depends on it.

Comment: This is quite helpful, So i actually started a new way of doing it someone who had already previously done it, i'm getting a whole new set of errors now. but i'm no longer getting the error with the registry problems. 

This is actually very helpful. If you use discord if you could message me so i could ask you a few more questions a little more quickly i'd appreciate that.

Otherwise

I believing I'm having an issue rendering,https://pastebin.com/3GZbrXMK

This is the error I'll update Github. The math will change! i'm more focused on getting it working where i no longer crash first.

Comment: drizzs#9185 If you're interested in helping me a bit more! Also this is 1.14.4 my bad!

Comment: Your build.gradle file said 1.14.3 ;) Your current problem is that your particle [passes its frame counter to an array of size 1](https://github.com/drizzs/GrassWorld-1.14/blob/master/src/main/java/com/drizzs/grassworld/api/particle/types/EnchantedBlack.java#L94). For more help than I can really do on SO, head over to [the Forge forums](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/forum/70-modder-support/) where back and forth replies are better suited.

Comment: Thats because there's no mappings for 1.14.4 yet it all says 1.14.3.

Comment: Ah! Yes, you are correct. I'd just skimmed the file to figure out what version you were on and didn't realize that. :)